# Reverse blob order by any axis in caffe

Tags: neural-network, caffe

Is there a way of reversing some axis in the blob (N x C x H x W -> N x C x Rev(H) x W or Rev(N) x C x H x W)? The only idea I have is to slice it by this dim to N blobs with shape 1 (by required axis) and then concat in reverse order. Is there any better way?

Because I don't want to make slice with 128 tops (or smth like that) and then concat with 128 bottoms. And I'm not sure about the productivity.

Also I can't use BatchReindex because it requires 2 bottom blobs, but I must emulate it with caffe layers and with 1 bottom. And I can't manually extend caffe.

Reason of restrictions: it should work with unmodified caffe on other computers.

Comment: use hdf5data layer to produce the second bottom for batchreindex layer

Comment: @Shai : Maybe I get this wrong, but I think that in case the blob size is constant,  you can add a simple additional input blob and fill it with the desired indices, without the need for hdf5data.

Comment: @rursw1 what "simple [...] input blob" can have an arbitrary index values? for me hdf5 is the simplest way...

Comment: See for example py-faster-rcnn's im_info blob: in prototxt: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/models/pascal_voc/ZF/faster_rcnn_end2end/test.prototxt Using it: lib/fast_rcnn/test.py -> blobs['im_info'] = np.array ... (Sorry for the poor formatting, I don't know how to properly format comments :( )

Comment: In case unmodified caffe refers to SSD-enabled caffe, you have the Permute layer that does exactly what you need.